# How to install amd64 libc6 libraries on arm64?

Tags: apt, dpkg, virtualization

I have a deb package from a vendor that's been compiled for amd64. I'm currently running Ubuntu server for ARM.

When I originally ran `dpkg` I was yelled at due to an architecture mismatch.

So I firt installed QEMU:

```
apt install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
```

I was able to install the package without any issues, but when running the binary, I get the following message:

```
x86_64-binfmt-P: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
```

It looks like we're trying to dynamically link to a amd64 library from libc6 that I don't have.

What voodoo is required to obtain it?

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies? Check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory#27469489) out.

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies installed for the package? It doesn’t seem so. This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory#27469489) has a good write up.

Comment: This is a package from a third-party vendor that is not available in a public apt repository so `apt-rdepends` doesn't work. This file is part of libc6 (default standard libraries), but I'm not sure how to download the non-arm version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the moderator was so nice…

Try `dpkg-deb -f <package>.deb Depends` to view the dependencies, or you can follow the link below. Very succinct.

Another option that’s doing what you’re doing but in reverse is [here](https://www.slothparadise.com/download-packages-and-dependencies-different-architectures-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amd64.list <<EOF
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
EOF
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libc6:amd64
```

---

Alternatively, if you only need ld and no other dependencies, you can skip multiarch and try installing the `libc6-amd64-cross` package, which contains:

> /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

To get `qemu-x86_64` to use it automatically:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/qemu-binfmt/
sudo ln -nsf /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu /etc/qemu-binfmt/x86_64
```